# Phpinfo.php browser trying to download instead of running

Tags: php, iis-7

HI I am trying to configure IIS7 to run PHP on a windows 2008 server machine.

I have followed this guide, [php running on IIS7](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php)

Everything went well and I am sure it was working!!

However now when I try and run phpinfo.php the browser wants to download the page rather than running the script.

The handler mapper is configured the same as the the example.  fastCGI/CGI is installed and enabled.

a normal index.html open no problem.

I have checked permissions, created a new empty site apart from phpinfo.php

I developed the site on my pc in a xampp environment where everything work great.  First time I have tried to convert a site from xampp to IIS.

Their is no entry in the MIME Types, I am wondering if the WEB.CONFIG file is the issue but I don't know enough about what the file should/shouldn't contain.

thanks for any help

Comment: Why would you even want to run php on IIS, there are much better solutions for php

Comment: I have no choice the companies webserver is IIS.  I developed the webpage at home where I run XAMPP and PHP

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://php.iis.net/ to install php into your IIS setup. It comes with a manager to help you easily implement php in to your iis server and is way easier then trying to configure it manually. Hope this helps.

Comment: Will this install over the top of the current php install?  will it have a knock effect to existing sites that are ok on IIS already?

Comment: Hmm... Having a bit more of a look into it it seems best to remove php before going down this route and then allow the WPI (Web platform installer) to just do everything for you....